# Parsing JSON from file

Tags: jquery, html, json

I want to get data out of a JSON file and show it. I am trying to do this with jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var url = 'http://domain.com/test/json.json';
   $.getJSON(url, function(data){
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         if (json[i].Active === "True") {
            $('<li />', {text : data[i].Name}).appendTo('.feed');
         }
      };
   });
});
```

JSON file looks like this:

```
 {"List":[
        {"Name":"Name 1","Active":"True"},
        {"Name":"Name 2","Active":"False"},
        {"Name":"Name 3","Active":"True"},
        {"Name":"Name 4","Active":"False"},
        {"Name":"Name 5","Active":"True"},
        {"Name":"Name 6","Active":"True"},
        {"Name":"Name 7","Active":"False"},
        {"Name":"Name 8","Active":"True"},
        {"Name":"Name 9","Active":"False"},
        {"Name":"Name 10","Active":"True"}
    ]}
```

HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="feed">
   <li>Name 1</li>
   <li>Name 3</li>
   <li>Name 6</li>
   <li>Name 8</li>
   <li>Name 10</li>
   //etc...
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your question? What are your errors? And besides that: The JSON response is inside the "data" object - you are not accessing it at all.

Comment: @gulty nothing is showing up... it's blank.

Comment: change json to data inside your getJSON function - if it's still not working you have to start debugging your code using console.log(data.Name) for instance.

Comment: looks like you are trying to access the json file from a different domain which isn't allowed due to the same origin policy: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy you have to change the htaccess file to allow your request on the destination server or use jsonP

Comment: it is not defined because your response is empty. you can't access the .json file from a different domain.

Comment: thanks @gulty it works for local file now in Firefox not Chrome. will try changing the htaccess now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var url = 'http://domain.com/test/json.json';
   $.getJSON(url, function(data){
      for (var i = 0; i < data.List.length; i++) {
         var item = data.List[i];
         if (item.Active === "True") {
            $('<li />', {text : item.Name}).appendTo('.feed');
         }
      };
   });
});
```